# Present perfect for actions that are still ongoing or have just finished

Tags: present-perfect, perfect-constructions, perfect-continuous

Can present perfect be used in the following situations? Present perfect continuous is the usual choice, but do native speakers use present perfect simple too?

1. "It has rained for two hours" = It is no longer raining.
2. "It has rained for two hours" = It is still raining.
3. "I have waited for two hours = I am still waiting.
4. "I have waited for two hours = I have stopped waiting.
5. "How long have you waited?" = The person is still waiting.
6. "How long have you waited??" = The person has just made decision to go home. Or it is because of something else that he is no longer going to wait.
7. "How long has it rained?" = It is still raining.
8. "How long has it rained?" = It has stopped raining.

Comment: It has rained for two hours. **implies** it is raining at the time of speaking. The kid's been screaming for ten minutes. Both start in the past and imply ongoing action.

Comment: None of these quoted "present perfect simple" examples would likely be spoken by a native speaker of American English.

Comment: @Lambie, do you mean the statements marked by = 
 (I mean those written after "=") and written next to the sentences are correct for BrE speakers? I mean do they express those ideas?

Comment: This has zero to do with BrE speakers. It is just English. And, an AmE speaker might very well say them. "It has [just] rained for two hours, and you are still complaining about a dry garden?"

Comment: @Lambie, So  are all these  correct? "It has rained for two hours" = It is no longer raining.

"It has rained for two hours" = It is still raining.

"I have waited for two hours = I am still waiting.

"I have waited for two hours = I have stopped waiting.

"How long have you waited?" = The person is still waiting.

"How long have you waited??" = The person has just made decision to go home. Or it is because of something else that he is no longer going to wait.

"How long has it rained?" = It is still raining.

"How long has it rained?" = It has stopped raining.

Comment: You seem to be repeating yourself. With the PP, the action is ongoing at the time of speaking **or** when the action began precisely is not the point. "He has lived there for two years."

Comment: @Lambie, you mentioned one  of the verbs (to live)  which can be used in both present perfect continuous and present perfect simple to talk about an action which is ongoing as our textbooks teach us, but I was asking if the statements written next to the sentences in present perfect simple in my original post express the same idea as present perfect in each of them. As in "It has rained for two hours"  is understood as = It is no longer raining and the rest sentences are explained in the same way.

Comment: And I have now said no three times, I think. It has rained for two hours.= At the time I say this the raining has **been coming down for two hours**. It says nothing about whether or not the rain has stopped.

Comment: @Lambie, But isn't it true that present perfect simple isn't usually  used instead of present perfect continuous to  talk about an action which is still ongoing? Don't native speakers use present perfect continuous for such  actions?  You said "an AmE speaker might very well say them. "It has [just] rained for two hours, and you are still complaining about a dry garden?"  Aren't you talking about an uncommon usage which is probably different from what BrE speaker might say? And when you said  "might very well say them" did you mean my sentences with those ideas which they express?

Comment: @Lambie Or did you mean none of them like the rain example  say anything about whether or not the action has stopped with present perfect. Sorry, but it's not easy :(

Comment: No, no and no. The PP continuous emphasizes the ongoingness of the action but the PP simple does not mean the action isn't ongoing **at the time of speaking**. I beg of you: Stop trying to ascribe differences to AmE and BrE usage here. This is NOT true: "But isn't it true that present perfect simple isn't usually used instead of present perfect continuous to talk about an action which is still ongoing?" One emphasizes the action; the other the time, but both mean it is still **raining at the time of speaking**.

Comment: @Lambie, different native speakers say different things. Another native speaker said that all the sentences are unnatural with present perfect and "I wouldn't use 1 or 2. I'd say "It's been raining for two hours" if it were still raining. If it's stopped, I'd say "It rained for two hours earlier/yesterday/on Tuesday."

Comment: That native speaker says present perfect doesn't mean it's still raining. That's why I said the difference between them is difficult. But for us it's quite helpful to know different opinions.  There is a clear differeence between their opinion and yours: And, an AmE speaker might very well say them. "It has [just] rained for two hours, and you are still complaining about a dry garden?" –

Comment: @AntoniaA I really don't care what they say. They are probably not English teachers or writers or grammarians. There is no difference between PPS and PPC in BrE and AmE English with regard to standard usage.

Comment: @Lambie Could you please suggest textbooks I could use? Those native speakers are teachers, but what they say isn't helpful at all.

Comment: ckfinder/userfiles/files/Advanced%20Grammar%20in%20Use%202nd%20Edition.pdf Advanced Grammar in Use This is from Cambridge University Press which has the best books. You have to regoogle this.

Comment: @Lambie, Thank you!

Comment: I'll reiterate at this point that an American speaker would never say "It has rained for two hours" (except in some remote circumstances not worth describing here). We would say "It's been raining for two hours" if it's still going and "it rained for two hours" if the raining is over. That's real life. Don't be so obsessed with rules that you don't listen to how people actually talk.

Comment: @cruthers, do you mean an American English speaker would  never  say  'it has rained for two hours " if it's still raining?

Comment: Right. Also wouldn’t say it if it stopped raining.

Comment: @cruthers, but your opinion is different from Lambie's. Am I right? I just want to make sure I don't misunderstand so I can take different opinions of native speakers into account and be aware of both uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all cases the present perfect indicates a state that continues to the present.  It doesn't say anything about it continuing into the future. It could stop at the time of speaking or it could continue.

For the "waiting" examples,  it would be possible to say

> I've waited for two hours, so I'm going home now.

> I've waited for two hours, but I'll just give him another 30 minutes.

In the first case, the person is stopping the wait at the time of speech, and not in the second case.  Without the second half of the sentence the first part doesn't say anything about when the person will stop waiting.

In the "rain" examples, it would be unlikely for the rain to stop just as you speak (it would be a real coincidence!).  If you were speaking after the rain had stopped you would use the past tense:

> It rained for two hours this morning, but it stopped 10 minutes ago.

I'd prefer "It has been raining" in the rain examples, although there isn't much difference between the present perfect and present perfect continuous in the meaning.

Comment: regarding this part "I'd prefer "It has been raining" in the rain examples, although there isn't much difference between the present perfect and present perfect continuous in the meaning." When is there no difference between present perfect continuous and present perfect  when the action has finished/it has stopped raining or when it's stiill raining?